# Extract parts of log in Python to import to Excel

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get part of a log (txt file) using regex but I'm needing some help. Basically the log comes like this:

```
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE  Event Loop - noop
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE     Exponential histogram:
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE     hist[ 0]: <      0.001: 728941854
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE  Event Loop - noop: samples: 728941854; avg: 0.00; min: 0.00; max: 0.00
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE  Data Quality Monitor Thread Processing Time
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE     Exponential histogram:
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE     hist[ 4]: <      0.016:         3
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE     hist[ 5]: <      0.032:        23
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE     hist[ 6]: <      0.064:        14
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE     hist[ 7]: <      0.128:         4
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE     hist[ 8]: <      0.256:         6
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE     hist[ 9]: <      0.512:         1
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE     hist[10]: <      1.024:         2
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE  Data Quality Monitor Thread Processing Time: samples: 53; avg: 0.08; min: 0.01; max: 0.67
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE  Client Hugepage Memory:   649/4096 MB 
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.836 SRV02    NOTICE  DQM: Num R: 0 RD: 0 ED: 0 W: 0 WH: 0 Q: 0 D: 0 DF: 0
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.836 SRV02    NOTICE  Num G: 0 M: 0 S: 0 D: 0 U: 0 R: 0 N: 0
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.836 SRV02    NOTICE  num_template_allocs                       =          4
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.836 SRV02    NOTICE  num_template_frees                        =          0
Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.836 SRV02    NOTICE  num_internal_book_allocs                  =         24
```

and I need to get the information about the "Exponential histogram", so, in this example I need to identify the string "Exponential histogram" and get all the "hist[..." to import to a spreadsheet. Also I need this information:

```
samples: XX; avg: X.XX; min: X.XX; max: X.XX
```

So, in the example above, I'll need to extract and rearrange the data like this, where "Event Loop - noop" and "Data Quality Monitor Thread Processing Time" need to be repeated in each line in order to identify the histogram:

```
Event Loop - noop;hist[ 0];0.001;728941854
Event Loop - noop;samples;728941854;avg;0.00;min;0.00;max;0.00
Data Quality Monitor Thread Processing Time;hist[ 4];0.016;3
Data Quality Monitor Thread Processing Time;hist[ 5];0.032;23
Data Quality Monitor Thread Processing Time;hist[ 6];0.064;14
(...)
Data Quality Monitor Thread Processing Time;hist[ 10];1.024;2
Data Quality Monitor Thread Processing Time;samples;53;avg;0.08;min;0.01;max;0.67
```

Somebody can help me how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example output, you have data that does not exist in your sample input.  Specifically you have more `"Data Quality Monitor Thread Processing Time"` strings then there are in your data.  It seems you want to keep the nearest indented header?

Anyway, I think it would be easier to just pull the data using a few different regex statements instead of trying to make one all encompassing one:

```
import re
hists = re.findall(r'(hist\[\s\d+\]).*?(\d+\.\d+).*?(\d+)',input)
sample_avg_etc = re.findall(r'(samples): (\d+); (avg): (\d+\.\d+); (min): (\d+\.\d+); (max): (\d+\.\d+)',input)
```

If you need to keep the local header as you show in your sample output.  I don't think you want to use regex.  Instead just write a parser which will extract your data.

You can start this by stripping each line of its `Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE` and then targeting the data line by line, keeping track of the last header.  See the comments, the below returns exactly what you listed above:

```
import re

def parse(data):
    lines = data.split('\n')  # get the lines by splitting on the newline char
    lines = [line[len("Tue Feb 24 17:51:10.835 SRV02    NOTICE  "):]  for  line in lines]  # remove the number of characters equal to the logging info
    out = []
    header = ''
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('   '):
            if line.strip().startswith('hist'):
                out.append(header + ";" + extract_hist_data(line))  # outsource the specific extracting to a function for ease of readability
        else:                      # header/samples line
            if all(i in line for i in ("samples", "avg", "min", "max")):  # if the line contains all these keywords
                out.append(header + ";" + extract_stat_data(line))  # outsource the specific extracting to a function for ease of readability
            else:  # Treat as a header
                header = line
    return '\n'.join(out)

def extract_hist_data(line):
    data = re.findall(r'(hist\[\s*?\d+\]).*?(\d+\.\d+).*?(\d+)',line)
    if len(data) > 0:
        data = data[0]
    else:
        return ""
    return ';'.join(i for i in data)

def extract_stat_data(line):
    data = re.findall(r'(samples).*?(\d+).*?(avg).*?(\d+\.\d+).*?(min).*?(\d+\.\d+).*?(max).*?(\d+\.\d+)',line)
    if len(data) > 0:
        data = data[0]
    else:
        return ""
    return ';'.join(i for i in data)

def parse_log_file(log_file_path):
    with open(log_file_path,'r') as f:
        content = ''.join(i for i in f)
    return parse(content)

print parse_log_file('test.log')
```

Comment: Hey Joe, thank you so much for the amazing script. I edited the question to be easier to understand. Your script is very close of the ideal solution,  what is missing is just to repeat the header (the histogram names) in all the lines ("Event Loop - noop" and "Data Quality Monitor Thread Processing Time") so I can know which histogram my data belongs to. Running your script I'm having this output:      hist[ 4]: <      0.016:         3;samples;53;avg;0.08;min;0.01;max;0.67;, but I need something like Data Quality Monitor Thread Processing Time;hist[ 4];0.016;3

Comment: @user179589 Did you run the second bit of code? it retains the proper headers.  I don't think you fully utilized my answer if you are saying that is missing.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I missed the last part. Thank you so much, the problem is solved!